# Problem trying to send file to browser in JSF

Tags: jsf, download, jsf-2

Hi I've tried two different techniques for sending a file to a browser(making the user download a file). I've tried an example from myfaces wikipage

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    String fileName = "test.txt";
    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    OutputStream os = null;

    StringBuffer stringBuffer1 = new StringBuffer("Java Forums rock");
    ByteArrayInputStream bis1;
    try {
        bis1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(stringBuffer1.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        os = response.getOutputStream();

        while ((read = bis1.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

I have also tried using a component named fileDownload from PrimeFaces. Both give the same result:

I get a response from the server, the response contains text that should be in the file. The header is a follows:

```
X-Powered-By    Servlet/3.0, JSF/2.0
Server  GlassFish v3
Content-Disposition attachment;filename="test.txt"
Content-Type    text/plain
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Thu, 20 May 2010 06:30:20 GMT
```

To me this looks correct but for some reason I don't get to download the file, I just get this response in firebug.

Does anyone have any idea?, could it be a serversetting problem? I using glassfish 3

Thanks
/ Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like as if you're requesting this asynchronously (using Ajax) instead of synchronously. When you do so, then you will indeed never see the *Save As* dialogue. You should always request file downloads synchronously. I.e. use "plain vanilla" `h:commandLink` or `h:commandButton` for this instead of some ajaxical command component.